# $F: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt(t) (1+xt)}$

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I have to find $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} \sqrt(x)F(x)$ ?

First I noticed that $\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt(t)(1+xt)}=0$. Then I proved that the function is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^+$.

I was wondering if it was a good idea to cut the integral $F$ in two part. Let $R>0$ and $\int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt(t) (1+xt)}=\int_{1}^{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt(t) (1+xt)}+ \int_{R}^{+\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt(t) (1+xt)}$ because the problem seems to be in the second part.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

By making the sustitution $t=u^2$ we get

\begin{align*}
 \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}(1+xt)}&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2udu}{u(1+xu^2)}\\
&=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{2du}{1+xu^2}\\
&=\frac{2}{x}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{du}{\frac1x+u^2}\\
&=\frac2x\sqrt{x}\left[\tan^{-1}\left(u\sqrt{x}\right)\right]_1^{\infty}\\
&=\frac2{\sqrt x}\left[\frac{\pi}2-\tan^{-1}(\sqrt x)\right]
\end{align*}
Then,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt xF(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\pi-2\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x})\right]=\pi-2\lim_{x\to\infty}\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x})=\pi-2\left(\frac{\pi}2\right)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=\sqrt{tx}$ then $du=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{t}}dt$ this integral changes to $\int \frac{2du}{\sqrt{x}(u^2+1)}=\frac{2arctan(u)}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2arctan(\sqrt{tx})}{\sqrt{x}}$ substituting the limits of integral for t we have $\frac{\pi-2arctan(\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}$ thus the limit is $lim_{x\to \infty} (\pi-2arctan(\sqrt{x}))=\pi-2\frac{\pi}{2}=0$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$0<F(x)<\int_1^\infty{dt\over \sqrt{t}\>xt}={1\over x}\int_1^\infty{dt\over t^{3/2}}\qquad(x>0)\ .$$